# Python: How to loop through several ini files with ConfigParser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, configuration, arcgis, ini

I somewhat understand how to do looping in Python, seems easy enough to say "For each file in this directory...do something". I'm now having a hard time figuring out how to loop through a series of .ini files in a directory, read lines from them, and use the text in the ini files as variables in the same Python script. For example, [in this script](https://github.com/amarinelli/update-hosted-feature-service/blob/master/update.py), a [single .ini file](https://github.com/amarinelli/update-hosted-feature-service/blob/master/settings.ini) provides the values for 12 variables in the script. Currently, to run the script multiple times, one has to replace the single ini file with another one, that contains a different 12 variables. The script performs routine maintenance of an on-line mapping service provider..thing is...I have dozen's of services I'd like to manage with the script. From the script, it appears that the name of the .ini file is fixed, not sure it's even possible to loop through multiple ini file? The good news is, that the script is using ConfigParser.....I hope this makes sense!

```
[FS_INFO]
SERVICENAME = MyMapService
FOLDERNAME = None
MXD = D:\nightly_updates\maps\MyMap.mxd
TAGS = points, dots, places
DESCRIPTION  = This is the description text
MAXRECORDS = 1000

[FS_SHARE]
SHARE = True
EVERYONE = true
ORG = true
GROUPS = None

[AGOL]
USER = user_name
PASS = pass_word1
```

The script below is reading from the ini file above.

```
# Import system modules
import urllib, urllib2, json
import sys, os
import requests
import arcpy
import ConfigParser
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

class AGOLHandler(object):    

    def __init__(self, username, password, serviceName, folderName):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.serviceName = serviceName
        self.token, self.http = self.getToken(username, password)
        self.itemID = self.findItem("Feature Service")
        self.SDitemID = self.findItem("Service Definition")
        self.folderName = folderName
        self.folderID = self.findFolder()

    def getToken(self, username, password, exp=60):

        referer = "http://www.arcgis.com/"
        query_dict = {'username': username,
                      'password': password,
                      'expiration': str(exp),
                      'client': 'referer',
                      'referer': referer,
                      'f': 'json'}   

        query_string = urllib.urlencode(query_dict)
        url = "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/generateToken"

        token = json.loads(urllib.urlopen(url + "?f=json", query_string).read())

        if "token" not in token:
            print token['error']
            sys.exit()
        else: 
            httpPrefix = "http://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest"
            if token['ssl'] == True:
                httpPrefix = "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest"

            return token['token'], httpPrefix

    def findItem(self, findType):
        #
        # Find the itemID of whats being updated
        #        
        searchURL = self.http + "/search"

        query_dict = {'f': 'json',
                      'token': self.token,
                      'q': "title:\""+ self.serviceName + "\"AND owner:\"" + self.username + "\" AND type:\"" + findType + "\""}    

        jsonResponse = sendAGOLReq(searchURL, query_dict)

        if jsonResponse['total'] == 0:
            print "\nCould not find a service to update. Check the service name in the settings.ini"
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print("found {} : {}").format(findType, jsonResponse['results'][0]["id"])    

        return jsonResponse['results'][0]["id"]

    def findFolder(self):
        #
        # Find the ID of the folder containing the service
        #

        if self.folderName == "None":
            return ""

        findURL = self.http + "/content/users/{}".format(self.username)

        query_dict = {'f': 'json',
                      'num': 1,
                      'token': self.token}

        jsonResponse = sendAGOLReq(findURL, query_dict)

        for folder in jsonResponse['folders']:
            if folder['title'] == self.folderName:
                return folder['id']

        print "\nCould not find the specified folder name provided in the settings.ini"
        print "-- If your content is in the root folder, change the folder name to 'None'"
        sys.exit()


def urlopen(url, data=None):
    # monkey-patch URLOPEN
    referer = "http://www.arcgis.com/"
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    req.add_header('Referer', referer)

    if data:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req, data)
    else:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

    return response


def makeSD(MXD, serviceName, tempDir, outputSD, maxRecords):
    #
    # create a draft SD and modify the properties to overwrite an existing FS
    #    

    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    # All paths are built by joining names to the tempPath
    SDdraft = os.path.join(tempDir, "tempdraft.sddraft")
    newSDdraft = os.path.join(tempDir, "updatedDraft.sddraft")    

    arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft(MXD, SDdraft, serviceName, "MY_HOSTED_SERVICES")

    # Read the contents of the original SDDraft into an xml parser
    doc = ET.parse(SDdraft)  

    root_elem = doc.getroot()
    if root_elem.tag != "SVCManifest":
        raise ValueError("Root tag is incorrect. Is {} a .sddraft file?".format(SDDraft))

    # The following 6 code pieces modify the SDDraft from a new MapService
    # with caching capabilities to a FeatureService with Query,Create,
    # Update,Delete,Uploads,Editing capabilities as well as the ability to set the max
    # records on the service.
    # The first two lines (commented out) are no longer necessary as the FS
    # is now being deleted and re-published, not truly overwritten as is the 
    # case when publishing from Desktop.
    # The last three pieces change Map to Feature Service, disable caching 
    # and set appropriate capabilities. You can customize the capabilities by
    # removing items.
    # Note you cannot disable Query from a Feature Service.

    #doc.find("./Type").text = "esriServiceDefinitionType_Replacement" 
    #doc.find("./State").text = "esriSDState_Published"

    # Change service type from map service to feature service
    for config in doc.findall("./Configurations/SVCConfiguration/TypeName"):
        if config.text == "MapServer":
            config.text = "FeatureServer"

    #Turn off caching
    for prop in doc.findall("./Configurations/SVCConfiguration/Definition/" +
                                "ConfigurationProperties/PropertyArray/" +
                                "PropertySetProperty"):
        if prop.find("Key").text == 'isCached':
            prop.find("Value").text = "false"
        if prop.find("Key").text == 'maxRecordCount':
            prop.find("Value").text = maxRecords

    # Turn on feature access capabilities
    for prop in doc.findall("./Configurations/SVCConfiguration/Definition/Info/PropertyArray/PropertySetProperty"):
        if prop.find("Key").text == 'WebCapabilities':
            prop.find("Value").text = "Query,Create,Update,Delete,Uploads,Editing"

    # Add the namespaces which get stripped, back into the .SD    
    root_elem.attrib["xmlns:typens"] = 'http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.1'
    root_elem.attrib["xmlns:xs"] ='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'

    # Write the new draft to disk
    with open(newSDdraft, 'w') as f:
        doc.write(f, 'utf-8')

    # Analyze the service
    analysis = arcpy.mapping.AnalyzeForSD(newSDdraft)

    if analysis['errors'] == {}:
        # Stage the service
        arcpy.StageService_server(newSDdraft, outputSD)
        print "Created {}".format(outputSD)

    else:
        # If the sddraft analysis contained errors, display them and quit.
        print analysis['errors']
        sys.exit()


def upload(fileName, tags, description): 
    #
    # Overwrite the SD on AGOL with the new SD.
    # This method uses 3rd party module: requests
    #

    updateURL = agol.http+'/content/users/{}/{}/items/{}/update'.format(agol.username, agol.folderID, agol.SDitemID)

    filesUp = {"file": open(fileName, 'rb')}

    url = updateURL + "?f=json&token="+agol.token+ \
        "&filename="+fileName+ \
        "&type=Service Definition"\
        "&title="+agol.serviceName+ \
        "&tags="+tags+\
        "&description="+description

    response = requests.post(url, files=filesUp);     
    itemPartJSON = json.loads(response.text)

    if "success" in itemPartJSON:
        itemPartID = itemPartJSON['id']
        print("updated SD:   {}").format(itemPartID)
        return True
    else:
        print "\n.sd file not uploaded. Check the errors and try again.\n"  
        print itemPartJSON
        sys.exit()        


def publish():
    #
    # Publish the existing SD on AGOL (it will be turned into a Feature Service)
    #

    publishURL = agol.http+'/content/users/{}/publish'.format(agol.username)

    query_dict = {'itemID': agol.SDitemID,
              'filetype': 'serviceDefinition',
              'overwrite': 'true',
              'f': 'json',
              'token': agol.token}    

    jsonResponse = sendAGOLReq(publishURL, query_dict)

    print("successfully updated...{}...").format(jsonResponse['services'])

    return jsonResponse['services'][0]['serviceItemId']


def enableSharing(newItemID, everyone, orgs, groups):
    #
    # Share an item with everyone, the organization and/or groups
    #

    shareURL = agol.http+'/content/users/{}/{}/items/{}/share'.format(agol.username, agol.folderID, newItemID)

    if groups == None:
        groups = ''

    query_dict = {'f': 'json',
                  'everyone' : everyone,
                  'org' : orgs,
                  'groups' : groups,
                  'token': agol.token}    

    jsonResponse = sendAGOLReq(shareURL, query_dict)

    print("successfully shared...{}...").format(jsonResponse['itemId'])    



def sendAGOLReq(URL, query_dict):
    #
    # Helper function which takes a URL and a dictionary and sends the request
    #

    query_string = urllib.urlencode(query_dict)    

    jsonResponse = urllib.urlopen(URL, urllib.urlencode(query_dict))
    jsonOuput = json.loads(jsonResponse.read())

    wordTest = ["success", "results", "services", "notSharedWith", "folders"]
    if any(word in jsonOuput for word in wordTest):
        return jsonOuput    
    else:
        print "\nfailed:"
        print jsonOuput
        sys.exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #
    # start
    #

    print "Starting Feature Service publish process"

    # Find and gather settings from the ini file
    localPath = sys.path[0]
    settingsFile = os.path.join(localPath, "settings.ini")

    if os.path.isfile(settingsFile):
        config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        config.read(settingsFile)
    else:
        print "INI file not found. \nMake sure a valid 'settings.ini' file exists in the same directory as this script."
        sys.exit()

    # AGOL Credentials
    inputUsername = config.get( 'AGOL', 'USER')
    inputPswd = config.get('AGOL', 'PASS')

    # FS values
    MXD = config.get('FS_INFO', 'MXD')
    serviceName = config.get('FS_INFO', 'SERVICENAME')   
    folderName = config.get('FS_INFO', 'FOLDERNAME')
    tags = config.get('FS_INFO', 'TAGS')
    description = config.get('FS_INFO', 'DESCRIPTION')
    maxRecords = config.get('FS_INFO', 'MAXRECORDS')

    # Share FS to: everyone, org, groups
    shared = config.get('FS_SHARE', 'SHARE')
    everyone = config.get('FS_SHARE', 'EVERYONE')
    orgs = config.get('FS_SHARE', 'ORG')
    groups = config.get('FS_SHARE', 'GROUPS')  #Groups are by ID. Multiple groups comma separated


    # create a temp directory under the script     
    tempDir = os.path.join(localPath, "tempDir")
    if not os.path.isdir(tempDir):
        os.mkdir(tempDir)  
    finalSD = os.path.join(tempDir, serviceName + ".sd")  

    #initialize AGOLHandler class
    agol = AGOLHandler(inputUsername, inputPswd, serviceName, folderName)

    # Turn map document into .SD file for uploading
    makeSD(MXD, serviceName, tempDir, finalSD, maxRecords)

    # overwrite the existing .SD on arcgis.com

    if upload(finalSD, tags, description):

        # publish the sd which was just uploaded
        newItemID = publish()

        # share the item
        if shared:
            enableSharing(newItemID, everyone, orgs, groups)

        print "\nfinished."
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would just want to add another loop in your main and then place most of what you have in your main into a new function (in my example, the new function is called 'process_ini'.

So, try replacing everything from your name == main line through the end with:

```
def process_ini(fileName):
    settingsFile = os.path.join(localPath, fileName)

    if os.path.isfile(settingsFile):
        config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        config.read(settingsFile)
    else:
        print "INI file not found. \nMake sure a valid 'settings.ini' file exists in the same directory as this script."
        sys.exit()

    # AGOL Credentials
    inputUsername = config.get( 'AGOL', 'USER')
    inputPswd = config.get('AGOL', 'PASS')

    # FS values
    MXD = config.get('FS_INFO', 'MXD')
    serviceName = config.get('FS_INFO', 'SERVICENAME')
    folderName = config.get('FS_INFO', 'FOLDERNAME')
    tags = config.get('FS_INFO', 'TAGS')
    description = config.get('FS_INFO', 'DESCRIPTION')
    maxRecords = config.get('FS_INFO', 'MAXRECORDS')

    # Share FS to: everyone, org, groups
    shared = config.get('FS_SHARE', 'SHARE')
    everyone = config.get('FS_SHARE', 'EVERYONE')
    orgs = config.get('FS_SHARE', 'ORG')
    groups = config.get('FS_SHARE', 'GROUPS')  #Groups are by ID. Multiple groups comma separated


    # create a temp directory under the script
    tempDir = os.path.join(localPath, "tempDir")
    if not os.path.isdir(tempDir):
        os.mkdir(tempDir)
    finalSD = os.path.join(tempDir, serviceName + ".sd")

    #initialize AGOLHandler class
    agol = AGOLHandler(inputUsername, inputPswd, serviceName, folderName)

    # Turn map document into .SD file for uploading
    makeSD(MXD, serviceName, tempDir, finalSD, maxRecords)

    # overwrite the existing .SD on arcgis.com

    if upload(finalSD, tags, description):

        # publish the sd which was just uploaded
        newItemID = publish()

        # share the item
        if shared:
            enableSharing(newItemID, everyone, orgs, groups)

        print "\nfinished."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Starting Feature Service publish process"
    # Find and gather settings from the ini file
    localPath = sys.path[0]
    for fileName in ['settings.ini', 'flurb.ini', 'durf.ini']:
        process_ini(fileName)
```

You'd have to write all the ini filenames in the list found in the penultimate line of my example.

Alternatively, you could identify all the .ini files in the directory via code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Starting Feature Service publish process"
    # Find and gather settings from the ini file
    localPath = sys.path[0]
    fileNames = [os.path.join(localPath, i) for i in os.listdir(localPath) if i.endswith('.ini')]
    for fileName in fileNames:
        process_ini(fileName)
```

It also might help to set the working directory (e.g., os.chdir(localPath)), but I'm going off of what you already had.

Comment: Awesome man, thanks! I implemented exactly as you suggested, but something in if __name__ == "__main__": is failing: returns Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update.py", line 330, in <module>
    process_ini(fileName)
  File "update.py", line 314, in process_ini
    if upload(finalSD, tags, description):
  File "update.py", line 187, in upload
    updateURL = agol.http+'/content/users/{}/{}/items/{}/update'.format(agol.use
rname, agol.folderID, agol.SDitemID)
NameError: global name 'agol' is not defined

Comment: The good part about your answer, is that it successfully reads the ini file and creates the file to upload, just the upload part of the loop is bombing somehow. Perplexing.

Comment: @tpcolson, based on that error, you just need to pass agol to upload(). In both places where "upload(finalSD, tags, description)" occurs in your script, replace it with "upload(finalSD, tags, description, agol)".

Comment: That generated some new errors: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\GIS_Final\data\basedata\basemap\Maps\ArcGIS\ARCGIS_SERVER\GRSM_DISTURBANCE\test.py", line 331, in <module>
    process_ini(fileName)
  File "X:\GIS_Final\data\basedata\basemap\Maps\ArcGIS\ARCGIS_SERVER\GRSM_DISTURBANCE\test.py", line 318, in process_ini
    newItemID = publish()
  File "X:\GIS_Final\data\basedata\basemap\Maps\ArcGIS\ARCGIS_SERVER\GRSM_DISTURBANCE\test.py", line 216, in publish
    publishURL = agol.http+'/content/users/{}/publish'.format(agol.username)
NameError: global name 'agol' is not defined

Comment: Basically you just need to make sure that you are passing agol to every function that uses it. In my last response, I mentioned upload(), but it looks like you need to add agol to publish() enableSharing() as well. Remember that you have to both pass it and "receive" it. That means search for "publish(" and add "agol" to the items within the parentheses. Do the same for "enableSharing(". See: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm